# Sitecore is skipping items during publishing. How to troubleshoot and find out why?

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, publishing

I have a series of items that I had in a test instance of Sitecore, and I needed to publish them down to a Sitecore dev instance to do some debugging with them. All the publishing down from test to the master DB in dev worked fine. I then went to publish those items out to the web database in dev. All the publishing of the ancillary items (templates, layouts, renderings, sublayouts, media library items, etc.) worked fine, but my actual content items are getting skipped (well, technically the root node of the section I'm publishing is skipped, so nothing under it gets published, either). I have no clue why it's getting skipped -- is there a way to get visibility to that?

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Making a copy of the content item node and trying to publish that. SKIPPED.
- Adding a new item in the content tree of the same template type as the content node and trying to publish that. SKIPPED.
- Packaging, rather than publishing, the items from test, installing in dev and trying to publish. SKIPPED.
- Deleting all the related items from the web database and republishing in a different order (everything in the Layout folder prior to any templates). All the ancillary items republish fine. The content items are SKIPPED.

I'm a little stuck, and there's nothing in the logs that's helpful (it just shows that the publish starts and ends, but nothing to indicate why anything's getting skipped).

Appreciate any help or ideas on how to figure out why these particular items are not publishing.

Comment: Check if the template of your root node exists and is published on your target database.

Comment: Thank you -- I'd checked that already, and yes, all the required templates were out there.

Comment: @wildwend: What was the root cause of this? What was the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you transfer the items from master to web db directly?

From Sitecore Control Panel -> Database -> Transfer items to another database.

It really sounds like a workflow/publishing restriction issue as idisposable11 says. Check there's no workflow attached, check the workbox to make sure nothing is in the queue, make sure the items have been submitted for review/approved if they are in workflow, and check there isn't date/time set for publishing restriction.

You can probably add in a handler to the publish:itemXXX event, or there maybe something in the publish pipeline you could add to help log/debug and step through, would need to take a look when I am front of a machine with Sitecore installed.

Comment: Thank you -- the transferring did work, so we have a bandaid solution, at least. It doesn't explain why the publishing was skipped in the first place, so I am probably still going to report this to Sitecore Support and see if they have any ideas as to root cause.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Go to the item in Content Editor and on the **Publish** tab, click **Change** in the restrictions section.
2. Click the **Targets** tab.
3. On the targets tab, check which targets are allowed. Check the target you need to publish to.

I believe if you have nothing checked, Sitecore will publish to all available targets. [Check here](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/05/all-about-publishing-targets-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I was having a terrible time trying to figure out why my publishing would always be skipped for a particular target. This was the answer for my problem. For some reason, the target (our production server), was unchecked. I have no idea how that happened as changing those targets is not in any procedure that we have.

Answer (score 2):

There is another scenario that can cause this.  Hopefully this saves someone in the future.

If a higher level item is set to Never Publish (even if the change is ONLY saved to the master database), any child item (nested) will be automatically unpublished regardless of what is attempted.

You can track down the culprit if you right click to the left of the content tree and select Publishing Warnings.  The Warnings flag does not cascade downward as you would presume, but DOES affect any nested child.

In our case, somehow the /sitecore item was set to this accidentally, which caused any publish on the site to remove items.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Folder under which the item-to-be-published resides has a version. If it doesn't, the items will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at any publishing restriction defined? It could also be that there's a workflow defined for the content items being published.

Comment: Yep, we checked that. There's no publishing restriction and I marked the items as being approved for production. But thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Just to confirm, I removed the Workflow template from the base page template we're using, and the publishing still gets skipped, so it's apparently not a workflow thing.

Comment: I just had this same thing and it WAS a publishing restriction.  Third tab on publishing settings (Targets), the Publishing Target was unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in the Sitecore.config which is the Publishing.PublishEmptyItems. By default it is set to false. For me, setting it to true fixed the problem.

```
<setting name="Publishing.PublishEmptyItems" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing Sitecore v10.2 I was unable to publish to our newly created database. There is a new step needed for Sitecore v10.1:

> In the App_Data\items\ folder, make a copy of the Web folder.

> Rename the copy of the folder and the .dat file inside it. Use the database name (for example, web_preview) instead of web for the folder name and the file name (so the filename is similar to items.web_preview.dat).

[Source](https://thebitsthatbyte.com/sitecore-quicktip-new-steps-to-create-a-publishing-target-in-sitecore-10-1/)